# GitHub Issue with SSH Keys

Tags: git, github, ssh

So, I created a Github SSH Key for my Win10 PC. I used my e-mail that's linked to my Github account when creating my SSH key. However, the key is linked to some old account that I made that is linked to a different email and that I've never used. I even created a new SSH key with a different E-mail. Why is it contributing from another account? Even when I log into the unwanted account, there are no SSH Keys on the account. I'm so confused and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: erase all keys, wth git config set your email, then add your ssh keys.

Answer (score 0):

The contributions are not accounted by the ssh-key used but by the email you set in the `git-config` and that is stored in the header of a commit messages:

```
git config --global user.email "email@example.com"
```

If you previously configured `git` with your old email, update the config as above. If you will need to "rebrand" commit messages using `git commit --reset-author --amend`.